# Cancel an iOS release

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I created a new version for the iOS app to prepare for some release. For some reason, I need to cancel this release and create a new release(skipping some versions).

I don't see any option to cancel a release before submitting it to app store. Is there any way it can be done before submitting for review.

Comment: Don't cancel it, just change the version number to the new one

Comment: before submitting for review no need to chnage anything , upload the new build in the same verson number just increment the curent build count + 1 ; and upload it, thats all

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is actually off topic (although I did vote to close, initially.) This is a marketing-end software release question, and might be more appropriate for AskDifferent.com, but if it were about other parts of iTunes Connect, it would probably be considered "more acceptable."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cool thing about iTunes Connect is that it lets you edit most metadata for an app that hasn't been reviewed yet.

#### Updating Your App Version

First, click on your app version in the sidebar.

[image: A screenshot of iOS app submission versions in the iTunes Connect sidebar]

Then, scroll down. You'll see a textbox for your version number:

[image: A cropped screenshot of the version and rating information in an iTunes Connect app entry]

Just change that version to whatever version you want. The value in this text box is what is displayed to your users, but does not necessarily have to match the version number in your app's `Info.plist`.

#### Replacing an Uploaded Binary

If you've already uploaded a binary, you need to account for two things:

**Version Numbers** Your next upload needs to have a higher value for the Bundle Version (`CFBundleVersion`) than the previous binary, even if the "Short Bundle Version String" (`CFBundleShortVersionString`) is the same.

**Binary Submission:** You may have chosen your binary as part of your submission that you'd like to change. You may want to remove the old binary and attach your new one after it finishes processing.

If this is the case, hover over the build in the aptly named "Build" section of your entry to see the red removal icon.

[image: A screenshot of removing a binary to change it to a different one]

Click it to clear the old selection. Then, you'll be able to choose another binary.

#### When this Works

This only works for an app that has a state of "Prepare For Submission" or "Waiting for Review". If your app is waiting for review and you want to submit a new version, you'll see a banner at the top of that version's screen:

[image: A screenshot of the iTunes Connect banner with a link to remove a version from review.]

If your app is already submitted and approved, you'll need to submit a new version to the store.